# Tomcat and Eclipse: image files and css files blank

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am developing a Java EE project in Eclipse, and deploying it on Apache Tomcat. (Inside Eclipse, I right-click the project, and then "Run as" -> "Run on Server".)

For some reason however (my guess is Eclipse misconfiguration), the browser cannot locate any JavaScript or CSS files. For instance, the web page has this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" type="text/css" href="generated-res/css/main.css">
<script src="generated-res/scripts/all.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Clicking them in Firefox source view, however, just opens up a blank page. My Eclipse project has a WebContent directory, which contains, among other things, generated-res directory. I uploaded an image (about Eclipse Web Deployment Assembly) on http://imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/viewimage.php?id=4185 . Can anyone spot what is causing this problem?

I have Eclipse "Indigo Service Release 2," which contains Apache Tomcat v6.0.

Much oblige!

Comment: And you are sure that that web page is in WebContent, not any subdirectory?

Comment: Woody, actually, I dont know. The page is not a "static" page in some directory, but is generated dynamically. I downloaded the Eclipse project from a repository, and I havent created it originally. In addition, I am not too familiar with Apache Tomcat. I will investigate it further, though. Thanks!

Comment: When you go to the page, is the page at http://address:8080/projectname/yourfile.xhtml ? and given the address that you are at, can you select that path and add 'generated-res/css/main.css' and find the css file? Do you also have anything generating those files (as per the name) or using that path as something else?

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:8080/molgenis_apps/molgenis.do . I have tried appending some some paths at the end of the url, but without success. Also, I suspect the content is generated deep inside the application, and then given to a proper controller to serve it as response. The content is scattered into several FreeMarker template files, which are afterwards concatenated together.

Comment: In which case I suspect that the address isn't right, which is why it isn't working. In tomcat you can specify that a particular file pattern (such as css/* ) is handled by something such as a servlet etc. The mappings for all these files are in the web.xml - look there to see what the mapping is for your files, your path or you types. Are you sure if it is generted by something you have no control over, the path isn't css/main.css or just main.css? Try typing in your path as localhost:8080/molgenis_apps/css/main.css and localhost:8080/molgenis_apps/main.css, see if the file exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a molgenis specific issue. In the molgenis.properties file you should add the service that is responsible for delivering the files (this is done in a seperate service to allow for application level security rules). The service you need is 'core.servlets.FileService'

In your molgenis.properties a typical set of services would look as follows:

```
services = app.servlet.GuiService@/molgenis.do,\
    org.molgenis.framework.server.services.MolgenisXrefService@/xref,\
    org.molgenis.auth.service.MolgenisCaptchaService@/captchaImg,\
    org.molgenis.framework.server.services.MolgenisTmpFileService@/tmpfile,\
    core.servlets.FileService@/
```

This includes:
- the user interface
- services for Ajax based lookups
- captcha service for new registrations
- tmp files
- the files in WebContent

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. I was wrong in thinking it was caused by some Eclipse/Tomcat misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

From your query it looks like you mean you are using the open source molgenes project, so I would think asking them would be a good bet.

However, as a brief look I would say the css is generated as /css/main.css so to test try the address of:

localhost:8080/molgenis_apps/css/main.css